# Using regex pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

I created a regex pattern that works perfect, but I can't get it working in Java:

```
(\\"|[^" ])+|"(\\"|[^"])*"
```

applied to

```
robocopy "C:\test" "C:\test2" /R:0 /MIR /NP
```

gives (as it should)

```
[0] => robocopy
[1] => "C:\test"
[2] => "C:\test2"
[3] => /R:0
[4] => /MIR
[5] => /NP
```

in group 0 according to http://myregextester.com/index.php

Now, how do I get those 6 values in Java?
I tried

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("   (\\\"|[^\" ])+  |  \"(\\\"|[^\"])*\"   "); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(command);

System.out.println(m.matches()); // returns false
```

but the pattern doesn't even match anything at all?

Update
The original perl regex was:

```
(\\"|[^" ])+|"(\\"|[^"])*"
```

Comment: Not enough back slashes.

Comment: hmm compared to the original perl pattern (\\"|[^" ])+|"(\\"|[^"])*" I always added one back slash for string escaping. where do I need more? Thanks! Ah I think I got it. I have to double each, of course.

Comment: hmm no, I don't manage to do it \:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the regexp string is first processed by the compiler before making it to the regexp processor, you need to double every backslahs in the expression, and add additional slashes for every doublequote.

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\\\\"|[^\" ])+|\"(\\\\\"|[^\"])*\"");
```

Comment: I *think* the original is already a regex, so for example `\\"` stands for a single backslash and a quote, which needs to be translated to `\\\"`, as he did

Comment: @amit I think your interpretation is right, he meant for the regex engine to see `\\"` - a slash and a single quote. However, `\\\"` translates as `\"` after Java has its way with it, so you need two extra slashes.

Answer (score 2):

The `matches()` method is matching the whole string to the regex - it returns true only if the entire string is matching

What you are looking for is the [`find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method, and get the substring using the [`group()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29) method.

It is usually done by iterating:

```
while (m.find()) { 
  .... = m.group();
  //post processing
}
```

Comment: Thank amit, also helpful, unfortunately I can only select one correct reply \:

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf No problems, glad I could help. You should accept the solution the solved your problem, as you did. You can upvote an answer if you find it helpful - no limits on these:)

Answer (score 0):

`matches()`  tries to match the pattern on entire string. You should use `find()` method of the Matcher object for your case.

So the solution is:

```
System.out.println(m.find());
```